# Agora IO cloud recording stop function getting uploadStatus unknow and code 435

Tags: video-recording, agora.io

I need cloud recording in agoraIO via API. I have successfully got the responseId and by this responseId I have successfully start the could recording and got sid with 200 status code.
But When I call the stop() function it is showing error code:435. I have AWS3 account and input accessKey and accesSecrete. I have created bucket also. I have little but confused about bucket. I have added the AWS3's access.
Is it the bucket name only or anything else?
I appreciate any clue or modification.

```
Url: https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/#APPID#/cloud_recording/resourceid/#RecordingResponseId#/mode/mix/start
<cfset json_request_recording_start= {
    "uid": "#uid#",
    "cname": "#mychannel#",
    "clientRequest": {
        "token": "",
        "recordingConfig": {
            "maxIdleTime": 30,
            "streamTypes": 2,
            "audioProfile": 1,
            "channelType": 0, 
            "videoStreamType": 1, 
            "transcodingConfig": {
                "height": 640, 
                "width": 360,
                "bitrate": 500, 
                "fps": 15, 
                "mixedVideoLayout": 1,
                "backgroundColor": "##FF0000"
            }
        }, 
        "storageConfig": {
            "accessKey": "#accessKey#",
            "region": 3,
            "bucket": "#awsbucket#",
            "secretKey": "#secretKey#",
            "vendor": 2
        }
    }
}>
```

**Server Response**

```json
{ 
  "resourceId":"fgfdfgfgfgfgfgf",  
  "sid":"ff4trtrtrgfgfgfgf7825c4a81d9a2e33",  
  "code":435,  
  "serverResponse":{
    "fileList":"",
    "uploadingStatus": "unknow"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey CodeLover, any update on this I'm also facing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I got it working.

in my case the issue was because I was testing the recording just using APIs and not passing in any data from mobile/web to agora using agora client SDKs. that's why nothing get recorded and status always remained unknown.

After passing the data, recording worked as expected.

Also for additional debugging you can write Agora support to enable callback events, this way you can see all the events happening on agora side.

Comment: I have a question can same person , record stream who start live stream session means same uid and cname

Comment: What do you mean by passing data ? How did you do it ? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @MithunSarkerShuvro Passing the data means use the client side SDK to make actual calls or livestreams, without that, if you just only use the APIs, then it will always send code 435

Comment: I still don't get it,
make actual calls means
just start a call and leave it there right?
then we just first need to call acquire api and then start record api right?

Comment: @Bhumit070 that's right, start the call, leave it right there, then call the acquire api and start record api.

Comment: @ZahidRiaz I am trying it but it does not work whenever I start the recording and they try to query on that it just returns 404

Comment: @Bhumit070 I know its very frustrating, Are you using agora Postman collection to test out the recording? 
If the call is still alive and you've successfully acquire the recording resource, then should be able to query the recording after recording has been started.

Comment: Hello @ZahidRiaz yes first of all using agora APIs is very frustrating they do not throw any error when any error occurs they just give you sid and resourceid in my case it was that my AWS credentials were wrong and I was passing a uid which was already there in the call so I was not able to record the call, Agora should throw error like unauthorised or something to show that one of my credentials are wrong or something which helps returning 200 success response is not an option.

Comment: Hello @ZahidRiaz it was due to wrong aws-s3 credentials.

Answer (score -1):

The Body of your start request should look like this

```
{
    "cname":"{{AccessChannel}}",
    "uid":"{{RecordingUID}}",
    "clientRequest":{
        "recordingConfig":{
            "maxIdleTime":120,
            "streamTypes":2,
            "audioProfile":1,
            "channelType":1,
            "videoStreamType":0,
            "transcodingConfig":{
                "width":360,
                "height":640,
                "fps":24,
                "bitrate":800,
                "mixedVideoLayout":1,
                "maxResolutionUid":"1"
                }
            },
        "storageConfig":{
            "vendor":{{StorageVendor}},
            "region":{{StorageRegion}},
            "bucket":"{{Bucket}}",
            "accessKey":"{{AccessKey}}",
            "secretKey":"{{SecretKey}}"
        }   
    }
}
```

Agora has a Postman collection that makes setup easier to understand: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/6319646/SVSLr9AM?version=latest